# How long does it take to crawl and map the bitcoin network?

Tags: client, network

There are several websites that have data on the number of nodes in the network. For instance [coin.dance](https://coin.dance). About how long does it take to map the entire bitcoin network?

Comment: With mapping the entire bitcoin network you mean listing all nodes? This would never end because nodes go offline and new nodes join, some nodes change their IP addresses, to some nodes your node might never get in contact ...

Comment: Ah good point but to get the initial estimate as seen on coin.dance I was curious how long that might take.